# Copy file inside target directory in one module to another maven module

Tags: spring, maven

I am trying to dockerize weblogic application and deploy .ear file to weblogic server. This is a multi module application. I want to copy xxx.ear file into dockerfiles dir in my another module.

module1 --> target --> xxx.ear to module2 --> dockerfiles -->

Is this possible ?. I want to do this operation in install phase. Please comment if you need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it you are talking about a dependency? When you have multiple modules if your project and one is depend on another, you can simply add a maven dependency.

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.your.group</groupId>
     <artifactId>your-artifact</artifactId>
     <version>${your.artifact.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

And then what you will need to add maven profiles in your parent pom where you will build multiple modules as whole to run. Because when u change something in your dependency module, (lets say common module) you need to rebuild it to take effect. So that you can achieve by using maven profiles.

```
<profile>
    <id>Booking</id>
    <modules>
        <module>/your-common-module</module>
        <module>/your-service-module</module>  
    </modules>
</profile>
```

Then you can select the profile and build your project. which will lead to automatically build your common module and add it to your interested module as a dependency.

And when it comes to docker, you don't need to worry about manually copying anything since your all dependencies are already bind to ear.

If still you need to copy something into your docker image use this,

```
COPY /module-name/target/common-module.jar /home/src/common.jar
```

you can simply copy it into your docker work directory. And docker file should be in a place where the above common module is visible and adjust the path in your favor.

Comment: Hi Damith, I have a root module. I forgot to add that one. However I have solved the issue. After first module is built, second module will copy the *.ear file from first module using maven resource plugin. Now my code it working. But I feel that my method is not the best solution for this.

Comment: can you explain why are you not using it as a dependency ? I am not clear with that part?